# How to interpret a boxenplot?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

could you help me to interpret this boxenplot, I've never used them or learn about them and I can't find clear information about them neither.

code :

```
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
ax = sns.boxenplot(x=members["age"], color = "r")
plt.xlabel("Âges")
plt.title("Répartition des âges des membres")
```

Comment: @DerekO No, [sns.boxenplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxenplot.html).  *"Originally named a “letter value” plot because it shows a large number of quantiles that are defined as “letter values”. It is similar to a box plot in plotting a nonparametric representation of a distribution in which all features correspond to actual observations. By plotting more quantiles, it provides more info about the shape of the distribution, particularly in the tails. For a more extensive explanation, you can read [this paper](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/letter-value-plot.html)"*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How boxen plot is different from box plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52403381/how-boxen-plot-is-different-from-box-plot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see https://madhuramiah.medium.com/some-interesting-visualizations-with-seaborn-python-ad207f50b844

The boxenplot shows the distribution based on the quartiles.   The distribution range shows the activity at certain numeric ranges, say sale price.  It also show the median sales price as a horizontal black line.   boxen plots give you an idea of volume at what price.